# Trying to do Server/Client integration using Flask/Typescript

Tags: python, typescript, flask, server, vercel

When I run my code, for some reason he POST request does not work. When I press the button, the program should record me and then send the recording to the server. The server will analyze the recording and then send to the front-end that it got the recording. However, the POST request is not initiated.

Here is my Flask Server (app.py):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/receive-recording', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  # Allow both GET and POST
def receive_recording():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            audio_data = request.data
            # Process the audio_data as needed
            return jsonify(message='I got the recording')
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify(error=str(e)), 400
    else:
        return jsonify(message='Hello! This is the audio recording endpoint.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my Typescript File (App.tsx)

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState<Blob | null>(null);
  const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState<string>('');

  const mediaRecorder = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);
  const chunks: Blob[] = [];

  const startRecording = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        mediaRecorder.current = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.current.ondataavailable = (event) => {
          if (event.data.size > 0) {
            chunks.push(event.data);
          }
        };
        mediaRecorder.current.onstop = () => {
          const recordedBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
          setRecording(recordedBlob);
          chunks.length = 0; // Reset chunks
        };
        mediaRecorder.current.start();
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error starting recording:', error));
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    if (mediaRecorder.current) {
      mediaRecorder.current.stop();
      if (recording) {
        sendRecording();
      }
    }
  };

  const sendRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/receive-recording', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: recording,
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setServerResponse(data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending recording:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Audio Recording and Communication</h1>
      {!recording ? (
        <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording and Send</button>
          <audio controls src={URL.createObjectURL(recording)} />
          {serverResponse && <p>Server Response: {serverResponse}</p>}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have some other CSS files but these two files are the ones controlling the backend. If you need the rest of the setup, please inform me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K7ur.png)

Comment: Is the Flask server also serving your static JavaScript bundle?  If not, then you are trying to call your static server instead of the Flask server.

Comment: I am not rendering my Javascript file through flask. I am using Fetch API to create the connection. I run the flask server and the front end separately (front end is in react).

Comment: If you have two separate servers then the Fetch call will have to have the host name and the port of the Flask server as this won't be the front end server's address. Example:  fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/receive-recording'

Comment: So your saying that I should put 'localhost:5000/api/receive-recording' in the typescript file instead of 'localhost:5000/api/receive-recording'? Apologies if I misunderstood what you said.

Comment: Update: I changed the host name to the port of the flask server, but the post request does not go through. The weird part is that I made a catch statement in the typescript file to catch any errors and no errors come up. This means that the POST request just isn't even happening.

Comment: I think you've done what you need to for the API server address. The TypeScript code not getting called is another problem which is hard to diagnose with the sample you've given.